# Updating the User Information List

Tags: 2010, mysite, profile-sync

So I'm trying to update the User Information List in SharePoint (hidden list). My User Profile Service and Mysites are all synced correctly with the most up-to-date information. Is there a particular Timer Job that will update the User Information List though?

Comment: why you trying to update the UIL?

Answer (score 0):

There are two timer jobs that push data from the UPSA to the UIL. `User Profile Service Application - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization` and `User Profile Service Application - User Profile to SharePoint Quick Synchronization` are responsible for this. That said, sometimes the sync stops working correctly. In that case, you may want to try running `stsadm -o sync -deleteolddatabases 0` which will reset the sync status and when one of those timer jobs runs, will update the UIL correctly. You can also get the PowerShell version from [Replacing stsadm -o sync with PowerShell](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2016/04/replacing-stsadm-o-sync-powershell/).

Comment: So I tried both syncs and the information still didn't update. I then listed the databases with the stsadm command and both were in sync. Just in case though I did the stsadm delete command, then ran both syncs again. Unfortunately nothing changed still.